# Write a Mockito test to verify Class2 method invoked in Class1 method return value

Tags: junit, mockito

```
Class1 {
    private Class2 class2;
    public void f1() {
      class2.f2();
    }}
```

Right now I have Class2 instance mock injected into Class1 instance. 
I need to write a test to verify Class2 f2 method return value.
How do I do it?

Comment: if class2 is a mock, then it will return whatever you set it up to return.. or the default value otherwise

Comment: Please show the test code you have already written. This will give us a better understanding of how far you've gotten, and what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you to be saying that in your test your `class2` member is a mock.  And if so, then you don't test the return value of the mock's `f2()` method call.  Since it is a mock, you can make the method call on the mock do/return whatever you need it to return.  The way to validate this is to use a verify statement to verify that the mock object's `f2() m`ethod was invoked.  If the `f2()` method had been passed parameters, you could also verify that it was invoked with the correct parameters passed.  Then you don't have to care or worry about what it returns because you are verifying that it was called as expected.  You will test the *actual* `f2()` method in a unit test for that class and can verify in that test that it does what you expect, but here where you are testing Class1 you just need to verify the method was called as expected.

See https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of Mockito.spy and Whitebox to assert that the delegate reference is invoked.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.Whitebox;

public class MockitoSpy {


    public class ClassTwo {
        public void doAThing(){}
    }

    public class ClassOne {
        private ClassTwo clazz2 = new ClassTwo();
        public void invokeClassTwo() {
            clazz2.doAThing();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testDelegationCall() {
        //Create the Object that will be our Spy
        ClassTwo twoRef = new ClassTwo();
        //Make the actual SPY reference
        ClassTwo spy = Mockito.spy(twoRef);
        //Configure the spy to not invoke the actual code -- that's not what we're testing.
        Mockito.doNothing().when(spy).doAThing();

        //Create the Object we want to test.
        ClassOne testInstance = new ClassOne();

        //Replace the field named 'clazz2' in the testInstance with our Spy
        Whitebox.setInternalState(testInstance, "clazz2", spy);

        //Make the call to the testInstance
        testInstance.invokeClassTwo();

        //ASSERT that the spy was called the number of times we would have expected
        Mockito.verify(spy, Mockito.times(1)).doAThing();

    }

}
```